# Why is my view like this on swift I updated it and now im able to just slide down and be able to go back to the last page XCODE 11

Tags: swift, xcode, view

[image]

wasn't like this till I updated to Xcode 11

Answer (score 0):

Use this when you present ViewController:

```
   viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
   self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```